# Detecting a palindrome in php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am trying to create a program which determines if a string is a palindrome or not.

This is the error i'm getting.

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\task18.php on line 22

My code is below:

```
<?php

//TASK 18 PALINDROME
//use string split function to split a string into an array

$str = "Mum";
$str =strtolower($str);

$strArray = array();
$strArray = str_split($str);

$len = sizeof($strArray);
$reverseStr ="";

for($i=$len-1; $i>=0; $i--){
    $reverseStr .=$strArray[$i];
}
if ($strArray == $reverseStr) {
    echo " $strArray is a palindrome";
} else {
    echo " $strArray is not a palindrome";
}
```

Comment: echo " $strArray is not a palindrome";

Comment: You can't echo an array.

Comment: What do you want $strArray to say in this case?

Comment: it shouldnt say anything as mum is a palindrome.

Comment: Your final `if` is comparing `$reverseStr` to `$strArray` - that's comparing a string with an array.

Comment: Whatever happened to [strrev()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're comparing a string (`$reverseStr`) to an array (`$strArray`).

You need to edit the code to this:

```
for($i=$len-1; $i>=0; $i--){
    $reverseStr[] .=$strArray[$i];
}
```

This will then put the reversed word into an array. So `mum` would be correctly outputted as `mum`, and test would be `tset`, but in an array.

This will then make the `if` pass, but you can't echo an array, so you should just echo out `$str`.

Full code:

```
$str = "mum";
$str =strtolower($str);

$strArray = array();
$strArray = str_split($str);

$len = sizeof($strArray);
$reverseStr = array();

for($i=$len-1; $i>=0; $i--){
    $reverseStr[] .=$strArray[$i];
}
if ($strArray == $reverseStr) {
    echo "$str is a palindrome";
} else {
    echo "$str is not a palindrome";
}
```

or if you need to use `$strArray` to be in the `echo`, you can use `implode()`:

```
echo implode($strArray). " is/is not a palindrome";
```

If you want to make it shorter, you can use this:

```
$str = strtolower("Mum");
$strArray = str_split($str);
$len = sizeof($strArray);
$reverseStr = array();
for($i=$len-1; $i>=0; $i--)
    $reverseStr[] .=$strArray[$i];
echo "$str is ".($strArray==$reverseStr ? "" : "not") . " a palindrome";
```

Comment: for this line here in the for loop  $reverseStr[] .=$strArray[$i]; what does the .= mean. does it just mean +=

Comment: `.=` appends something to the string. For example: `$str = "Hello"; $str .= " there!";` When `$str` is echoed it will be `Hello there!`. Without the `.` it would just be `there!` @Phill

Answer (score 1):

Description:- You can't Echo an array that's why you are getting this error.Because you are echoing a array which is not possible.Type Juggling(Variables are some time automatically cast to best fit).That's same happens with your code because you trying to echo a array and when php trying to convert it to string it fails.Here below is a code to check palidrome using str_split().

```
  <?php
$word = strtolower("mum");
$splitted = str_split($word);
$reversedWord = "";
$length = strlen($word);
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
    $reversedWord .= $splitted[$length - $i - 1];
echo $word == $reversedWord ? "It's a palindrome " : "It's not a palindrome";
?>
```

Comment: Your code is identical to the original. You've not changed anything.

Comment: The changes are the var to string in the line 22.

Comment: @beatalex now i had change it.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use given thing without using any php function.

```
$str="level";

for($i=0;$i<40000;$i++)

    if($str[$i])
        $count++;
    else
    break;


    for ($j=$count;$j >=0; $j--){
         $newStr.=$str[$j];
    }
    //echo $newStr;

        if($newStr==$str)
            echo  $newStr."  is a palindrome";

            else

            echo  $newStr."  is not a palindrome";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this, it works...

```
function fn_palindrome($palindrome) {
    $reversed = ''; 
    $original = $palindrome;
    $string = array(); $j = 0;
    $converted = (string) $palindrome;
    $palindrome = str_split($converted);
    $i = count($palindrome) - 1;
    while($i >= 0) {
        $string[$j] = $palindrome[$i];
        $j++; $i--;
    }
    $reversed = implode('', $string);
    if($reversed == $original) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```